# Is there a way to use video codecs for avi files in Mathematica?

Tags: video, compression

I would like to use *Mathematica* to create compressed **.avi** video files from image sequences. I read the [documentation on **.avi**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/AVI.html) but couldn't find a solution. In the documentation it says:

> - Internal`$VideoEncodings gives a list of video codecs available on your computer system.
> - Commonly available codecs include "YUV", "H261", "H263", "JPEG", "Uncompressed", "Cinepak", and "MotionJPEG".

but none of these video encoding options effectively reduces the file size. When I install the latest version of [QuickTime](http://www.apple.com/de/quicktime/download/) on my computer and use the applicable video encoding options, the exported **.mov** files are encoded. However, I would prefer to have **.avi** files due to compatibility reasons. If I check for available video encodings I get:

```
Internal`$VideoEncodings
```

> {"Animation", "BMP", "Cinepak", "Component Video", "DVCPRO - \ PAL",
>   "DV/DVCPRO - NTSC", "DV - PAL", "Foto - JPEG", "Grafik", \ "H.261",
>   "H.263", "JPEG 2000", "Keine", "Motion JPEG A", "Motion JPEG \ B",
>   "MPEG-4 Video", "Planar RGB", "PNG", "Sorenson Video", "TGA", \
>   "TIFF", "Uncompressed", "Video"}

I also have other ways to create **.avi** files using different software through *Mathematica* but I would love to have it the pure *Mathematica* way. I am using version 9.0.1. Are there any good alternatives to create a good quality video? I don't have the impression that the **.mov** files are of good quality...

**Edit 24/07/2014**

- QuickTime version 7.7.5 (1680.95.13)
- Mathematica version 9.0.1

Here is an example piece of code that I have created. It gives absolutely the same file size for each **.avi** encoding I use (note that I leave out one of the encoding methods since it conflicts with `FileNameJoin`):

```
engine = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"];
outDir = CreateDirectory[
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "AviExport"}]];

Cases[Internal`$VideoEncodings, Except["DV/DVCPRO - NTSC"]]
```

> {"Animation", "BMP", "Cinepak", "Component Video", "DVCPRO - PAL", \
>   "DV - PAL", "Foto - JPEG", "Grafik", "H.261", "H.263", "JPEG 2000", \
>   "Keine", "Motion JPEG A", "Motion JPEG B", "MPEG-4 Video", "Planar \
>   RGB", "PNG", "Sorenson Video", "TGA", "TIFF", "Uncompressed", "Video"}

```
ParallelMap[
  Export[FileNameJoin[{outDir, "engine" <> # <> ".mov"}], engine, 
    "VideoEncoding" -> #] &, 
  Cases[Internal`$VideoEncodings, Except["DV/DVCPRO - NTSC"]]];

ParallelMap[
  Export[FileNameJoin[{outDir, "engine" <> # <> ".avi"}], engine, 
    "VideoEncoding" -> #] &, 
  Cases[Internal`$VideoEncodings, Except["DV/DVCPRO - NTSC"]]];

Grid[Prepend[{#, N@FileByteCount[#]/1024^2} & /@ 
   FileNames["*mov", {outDir}], {"Filename", "File size [MB]"}], 
 Alignment -> Left]
```

> [image: mov files]

```
TableForm[Prepend[{FileBaseName@#, N@FileByteCount[#]/1024^2} & /@ 
   FileNames["*avi", {outDir}], {".avi file", "File size [MB]"}]]
```

> [image: avi files]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, actually my library will *import* AVI files but not *export* them.

Comment: @Simon "Bummer" as they say. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, annoyingly there **is** support in Media Foundation for an AVI media sink but only for Windows 8.1.

Comment: g3kk0, just to be clear, are you saying that you get uncompressed AVI regardless of which codec you select? This is (obviously) incorrect behaviour - I suggest stating your OS and QuickTime version in the question so that others with the same setup can comment on whether they see the same problem.

Comment: One thing strikes me as peculiar in this question: "*I don't have the impression that the .mov files are of good quality.*"  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I have the impression that the images appear much darker (maybe due to higher contrast) than in the avi files. But in fact I am not interested in the mov files. I would prefer avi.